# Hibernate can't handle three oneToMany collections within one entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I have hibernate entity that has three @OneToMany collections within it. During saving, Hibernate inserts only one at a time, causing other two fields to throw a "Field 'XXXX-Field-XXXX' doesn't have a default value" error.

I'm using Hibernate Core 5.3.7.Final, JPA 2.2

Main entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entityOneDto")
public class EntityOneDto extends Dto<EntityOneDto, EntityOne> {
private String entityId;
private String label;
private String testContent;
private Integer count;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<DocumentDTO> list1Documents;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<DocumentDTO> list2Documents;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<DocumentDTO> list3Documents;
```

DocumentDTO entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
public class DocumentDTO extends Dto<DocumentDTO, Document> {
private String documentId;
private String testContent;
private int count;
private String title;
private LocalDateTime date;
```

Hibernate logs:

```
    Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
    Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
    Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
    Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
    Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
    Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
    Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
    Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
    Hibernate: insert into entityOneDto (entityId, testContent, label, count, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into document (testContent, documentId, date, count, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into document (testContent, documentId, date, count, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into document (testContent, documentId, date, count, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into entityOneDto_document (entityId_id, list1Documents_id) values (?, ?)
    2019-04-30 18:20:29.830  WARN 55440 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
    2019-04-30 18:20:29.837 ERROR 55440 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'list2Documents_id' doesn't have a default value
    2019-04-30 18:20:29.983  INFO 55440 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
    2019-04-30 18:20:30.126 ERROR 55440 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement]
```

From what I can see, it creates three documents, but then inserts only one of them:

```
Hibernate: insert into entityOneDto_document (entityId_id, list1Documents_id) values (?, ?)
```

which is wrong, since connection table has main entity id and three fields for each of documents collection:
[hibernate' generated table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHVeK.png)

Please help. Can it be solved?

**UPDATE**: What is also weird, one of these listDocuments is also a PRIMARY key in entityonedto_document table. So I have 2 primary keys: entityId_id and list1Documents_id. List2 and list3 are "NN" and "Unique".

Comment: "Field 'list2Documents_id' doesn't have a default value" means that the field he is trying to insert is null, and in the database there is no default value defined for that field, you should check what data is being inserted

Comment: vc73, tnx for reply, but even with default value, it should insert actual values and not default one, especially considering the fact that it has these values(ids). Why bother creating table with 4 values if we only insert two in it? As for default value, I've read that each DB has different syntax for default value annotations which will make code more db dependent, which I'm trying to avoid.